# Honor your Father and your Mother?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I heard a Rabbi at the Central Synagogue in New York say that honoring your parents was not just to agree with them but to understand them.

How does the halacha deal with parents who are very angry people who often say upsetting things or who are hard to understand. When and how are you allowed to answer them?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41181/1713

Comment: I don't understand this question. What does parents' being angry have to do with their being unintelligible? And "When and how are you allowed to answer them?"? You mean like "I'm sorry, I didn't understand you. Can you explain it better?"?

Comment: @msh210 whats hard to understand ?

Answer (score 3):

This is answered in Shulchan Aruch in [סימן רמ - איזהו כבוד ואיזה מורא ודיניהם](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_33.html).

Short answer: grin and bear it.

The details - with some paraphrasing:
<sup>Yes. Translating would be nice, but I don't have the patience right now, as the details are rather intricate.</sup>

> **ג:** עַד הֵיכָן מוֹרָאָם, הָיָה הַבֵּן לָבוּשׁ חֲמוּדוֹת וְיוֹשֵׁב בְּרֹאשׁ הַקָּהָל, וּבָאוּ אָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ וְקָרְעוּ (ה) בְּגָדָיו וְהִכּוּהוּ עַל רֹאשׁוֹ וְיָרְקוּ בְּפָנָיו, **לֹא יַכְלִים אוֹתָם, אֶלָּא יִשְׁתֹּק**, וְיִירָא מִן מֶּלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים שֶׁצִּוָּהוּ בְּכָךְ.‏

Even if they humiliate you publically, you may not react disrespectfully. You have to remain silent and fear The One who commanded you to respect them

However, you may sue them for damages occured, as the Be'er Heitev says:

> ***באר היטב***  (ה) **בגדיו**. מיהו מותר לתבעו בדין כדלקמן ס''ח בהג''ה. ש''ך:

And again - one may not upset them, nor cause them [emtional] pain nor show any anger. However, some opinions let one prevent monetary damage:

> **ח:** עַד הֵיכָן כִּבּוּד אָב וָאֵם, אֲפִלּוּ נָטְלוּ כִּיס שֶׁל זְהוּבִים שֶׁלּוֹ, וְהִשְׁלִיכוּ בְּפָנָיו לַיָּם, **לֹא יַכְלִימֵם וְלא יְצַעֵר בִּפְנֵיהֶם וְלֹא יִכְעֹס כְּנֶגְדָּם**, אֶלָּא יְקַבֵּל גְּזֵרַת הַכָּתוּב **וְיִשְׁתֹּק**. הגה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאִם רוֹצֶה לִזְרֹק מָעוֹת שֶׁל בֵּן לַיָּם דְּיָכוֹל לְמָנְעוֹ, דְּהָא אֵינוֹ חַיָּב לְכַבְּדוֹ רַק מִשֶּׁל  אָב, אֲבָל לֹא מִשֶּׁל בֵּן (טוּר בְּשֵׁם ר''י) . וְאֵין חִלּוּק בֵּין לְכַבְּדוֹ אוֹ לְצַעֲרוֹ (ת''ה סִימָן מ') . וְדַוְקָא קֹדֶם שֶׁזְּרָקָן, דְּאֶפְשָׁר דְמִמְנַע וְלֹא עָבֵיד, אֲבָל אִם כְּבָר זְרָקוּהוּ, אָסוּר לְאַכְלוּמֵהּ אֲבָל יוּכַל לְתָבְעוֹ לְדִינָא (טוּר בְּשֵׁם הָרֹא''שׁ) . וְדַוְקָא אִם רוֹצֶה לִזְרֹק כִּיסוֹ לַיָּם, דְּאִית בֵּיהּ חֶסְרוֹן כִּיס, אֲבָל אִם רוֹצֶה לְהַעֲבִיר מִמֶּנּוּ רֶוַח בְּעָלְמָא, אָסוּר בְּכָל עִנְיָן (ר''ן פ''ק דְּקִדּוּשִׁין) . בֵּן שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ דִּין עִם אָבִיו, וְהָאָב הוּא תּוֹבֵעַ הַבֵּן, צָרִיךְ הַבֵּן לֵילֵךְ אַחַר אָבִיו אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַבֵּן הוּא נִתְבָּע וְדָר בְּעִיר אַחֶרֶת, שֶׁזֶּהוּ כְּבוֹד אָבִיו. אֲבָל הָאָב חַיָּב לְשַׁלֵּם לַבֵּן הוֹצָאוֹת, דְּאֵינוֹ חַיָּב לְכַבְּדוֹ מִשֶּׁל בֵּן (במהרי''ק שֹׁרֶשׁ נ''ח), כְּמוֹ שֶׁנִּתְבָּאֵר.‏

However, one may move far away if one cannot deal with them appropriatly:

> **י:** מִי שֶׁנִּטְרְפָה דַּעַת אָבִיו אוֹ אִמּוֹ, מִשְׁתַּדֵּל לִנְהֹג עִמָּהֶם כְּפִי דַּעְתָּם עַד שֶׁיְּרֻחַם עֲלֵיהֶם. וְאִם אִי אֶפְשָׁר לוֹ לַעֲמֹד, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּגְּעוּ בְּיוֹתֵר, יֵלֵךְ לוֹ וְיַנִּיחֵם, (יג) וִיצַוֶּה לַאֲחֵרִים לְנַהֲגָם כָּרָאוּי.
>
> ***באר היטב***  (יג) **ויצוה**. בט''ז כתב שהראב''ד השיג ע''ז דממ''נ אי מהני להם שמירה למה ילך ויניחם אם א''א לשמרם מה מהני צווי לאחרים בשמירה וכן כתב בדרישה וכן עיקר עכ''ל: ‏

Comment: Note: if the parent is yelling "you're a useless, good-for-nothing hooligan", Shulchan Aruch is saying you may not shoot back names at your parent. That does not mean you must believe that you are a useless, good-for-nothing hooligan! You are absolutely entitled to think, "God help my parents, they are messed up." (But maybe check with some other wise people to make sure your perspective is accurate.)