# Why does the Torah not include a specific command to love one's parents?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

This [related M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41197/5275) explains that there is no specific mitzvah to love one's parents and the concept is incorporated in the mitzvah of loving one's fellow.

There is a mitzvah to love the convert, one's fellow, and G-d himself. Why does the Torah not specify loving one's parents, rather than incorporating them into the mitzvah of one of the others (as stated in the linked answer)?

I heard (don't recall source, offhand) that one receives greater reward for performing a mitzvah because it was specifically commanded as a mitzvah than doing it because it is the natural, nice or logical thing to do.

If that principle is true, why shouldn't this mitzvah be explicitly listed so that one can receive greater reward for it?

Comment: Why do you think such a Mitzva should exist?

Comment: is there a mitzva to love yourself? loving parents is natural

Comment: @ray "loving parents is natural" - perhaps, it should be, but, we know that, in reality, it is not. There are numerous cases where children don't love their parents, and some outright hate them; some even violently. Regardless, there's a general rule (forgot exactly from where) that one receives greater reward from performing a mitzvah because it was commanded as a mitzvah rather than doing it b/c it was logical or natural.

Comment: @DanF i hear. but most people love their parents, no?

Comment: @ray As far as I know, yes. But, see my edits in the question. That's my main point. Mitzvot are not based on logic.

Comment: The options aren't "explicitly listed" or natural. The options are listed separately from other Jews and included with other Jews.

Comment: The question doesn't make clear why you're  asking about parents more than about, say, lefties.